# Sharing in ReactNative to Messenger, Mail and with Images

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement this and I see that ReactNative comes with the Share API somewhat exposed here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html

but I don't see how to say open up iMessage (or the android equivalent and do it with say an image, send a new message with an image) Or the mail, I want to tap the mail app and open it up with an image already in the email.

Is this even possible insofar as is it exposed already? I'm thinking not really because even the example code in react-native source code doesn't do this level of detail.

It seems like I need to use https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share

[image]